# VBA code for seeing the size of each worksheet in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I came across code online for my question, but it doesn't seem to work properly (unless I'm missing something).  I have a large excel file that I'm trying to cut down with a functioning code.

The code below calculates each sheet and posts the totals in a new worksheet, but the total output it gives me is 218MB.  The file size shown in properties is 162MB and I have no idea where the extra 56MB is coming from

```
ub GetEachWorksheetSize()
Dim strTargetSheetName As String
Dim strTempWorkbook As String
Dim objTargetWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim objRange As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim nLastEmptyRow As Integer

strTargetSheetName = "Sheet Sizes"
strTempWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp Workbook.xls"

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(before:=Application.Worksheets(1))
     .Name = strTargetSheetName
     .Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet"
     .Cells(1, 1).Font.Size = 14
     .Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
     .Cells(1, 2) = "Size"
     .Cells(1, 2).Font.Size = 14
     .Cells(1, 2).Font.Bold = True
End With

Set objTargetWorksheet = Application.Worksheets(strTargetSheetName)

For Each objWorksheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If objWorksheet.Name <> strTargetSheetName Then
       objWorksheet.Copy

       Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strTempWorkbook
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

       nLastEmptyRow = objTargetWorksheet.Range("A" & objTargetWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

       With objTargetWorksheet
            .Cells(nLastEmptyRow, 1) = objWorksheet.Name
            .Cells(nLastEmptyRow, 2) = FileLen(strTempWorkbook)
       End With

       Kill strTempWorkbook
     End If
Next
End Sub
```

I found another code below on another forum that is supposed to tackle the problem.  The code runs, but doesn't output anything.

```
Sub SheetsSize()

Dim a(), Bytes As Double, i As Long, FileNameTmp As String
Dim Sh, Wb As Workbook

Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
ReDim a(0 To Wb.Sheets.Count, 1 To 2)

' Turn off screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo exit_

' Put names into a(,1) and sizes into a(,2)
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Build the temporary file nane
FileNameTmp = .GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\" & Wb.Name & ".TMP"
' Save workbook
Wb.SaveCopyAs FileNameTmp
' Put workbook's name and size into a(0,)
a(0, 1) = Wb.Name
a(0, 2) = .GetFile(FileNameTmp).Size
' Put each sheet name and its size into a(i,)
For i = 1 To Wb.Sheets.Count
  Wb.Sheets(i).Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileNameTmp
  a(i, 1) = Wb.Sheets(i).Name
  a(i, 2) = .GetFile(FileNameTmp).Size
  Bytes = Bytes + a(i, 2)
  ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Next
Kill FileNameTmp
End With

' Show workbook's name & size
Debug.Print String(255, vbLf); a(0, 1), Format(a(0, 2), "# ### ### ##0") & " Bytes"

' Show each sheet name and its corrected size
For i = 1 To UBound(a)
Debug.Print String(255, vbLf); a(i, 1), Format(a(0, 2) * a(i, 2) / Bytes, "# ### ### ##0") & " 
Bytes"
Next

exit_:

' Restore screen updating and show error reason if happened
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Show the reason of error if happened
If Err Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"

End Sub
```

Looking for some help on getting the exact total or if i'm not understanding something correctly

Comment: The 56 is workbook properties that exist outside of the sheet I believe.

Comment: Another option without code is to rename the file with a .zip extension.  You can then double-click the file and examine the size of all the components.  It will warn you about changing the extension.  You can copy it to be safe, but never had a problem.

Comment: How many worksheets are in your workbook?

Comment: @urdearboy: 56M for workbook properties? I have been working on a workbook that was 13M in size (total) - and even then thought this was excessive!

Comment: Wouldn't trust the second code either: `a(0, 2) * a(i, 2) / Bytes` seems a strange way to calculate the size.

Comment: There are roughly 30 sheets in the workbook.  Trust me, if i could reduce it, i would.  There are all dependent on each other and would take significantly longer breaking them all out and opening them individually

Comment: Is there anyway to see the workbook properties?